# For new user first post/put request does not works in Algolia

Tags: c#, algolia

**Problem :-**

I am using `C# Web API's` to create new users.

Whenever I create a new user and sends first request to save data on `Algolia` `Index` from that new user it does not save data on `Algolia` `Index`.

But at second request it works and saves the data, any idea what could be the reason?

Everything works fine on local solution but when I deploy project problem occurs but just for very first time. Here are both scenarios for which issue is occuring

1. User is new
2. User was logged out and then logged in again

**I have tried :-**

I am using free version of Algolia , I have contacted with support they have offered two solutions.

1. One is to put `Wait()` after `asynchronous` call, this solution worked for sorting because there was inconsistency of same kind for sorting but this solution did not work for `SaveObject()`
2. Second solution they offered is to use paid version of Algolia :(

**Algolia Code in C# :-**

```
var createFeed = await feedIndex.SaveObjectAsync(feedDocumentObject);
createFeed.Wait();
```

Comment: Without some type of [minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is nothing more than a guessing game. For example, what "new user"? An algolia userId? Or a user in your system? Or? If an algolia user, are you properly awating the asyc result? i.e., `var res = client.AssignUserIDAsync("myUserID1", "c1-test");` or `var res = await client.AssignUserIDAsync("myUserID1", "c1-test");` Notice the `await` operator. Really need more information.

Comment: I am using ```async``` calls , code added now

Comment: The current sample does not make sense, re: `await feedIndex.SaveObjectAsync` is already awaitng the task; the 2nd line shouldn't even compile because at that point `createFeed` has already returned the result. You need to post the entire method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, think about to call the second Task using [ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-6.0) approach, if your requirement is guarantees the second step of your code will be executed after first step, this sample bellow has a little bit of how to your code be changed (conceptually, considering the object feedIndex is a FeedIndexType in C# code):

```
    Task<FeedIndexType> step1 = Task.Run<FeedIndexType>(() =>
    {
        //first step
        return feedIndex;
    });
    var createFeed = step1.ContinueWith((feedIndex) => 
    {
        feedIndex.SaveObjectAsync(feedDocumentObject);
    });
    createFeed.Wait();
```

You may see more about this approach in this article: [Difference Between Await and ContinueWith Keyword in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/difference-between-await-and-continuewith-keyword-in-C-Sharp/) and [Chaining Tasks by Using Continuation Tasks](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks/)